# Comparable MS Office 2016/2013 Alternatives for linux

Tags: wine, libreoffice, playonlinux, microsoft-office, productivity

I have tried MS Office 2010, 2013 via PLayonlinux. It is still buggy on Linux. I have tried LibreOffice, WPS, Freeoffice, ApacheOffice. But no alternatives seems to get along with Ms Office. If I open a file in WPS/Libre Office margins changes drastically, and nice arranged essays become mess. Not to mention it takes a lot of time to rearrange my all work.

So, **I am wondering is there really any open source or any way to work on Docs file which is compatible with MS office.**

Comment: Ask Microsoft to open-source their code for MS Office.

Comment: @DKBose - Lol, ask them in 30 years maybe. It only took them that long to open source Word 1.1a :P

Comment: To OP: Have you tried Office Online?

Comment: @DKBose hahaha dreams.. bro 

Comment: @AndroidDev lol true

Answer (score 3):

There is NO alternative that is as mature on the Linux platform or as intuitive if you have previously used MS Office.

HOWEVER, you have a few options that are better aligned with the future; The Cloud. You may create a Microsoft account at live.com etc. and freely use the online office version without any platform dependency. It may have some limitations but is perfectly compatible with the other MS office versions.

ALSO, you may want to try the google alternatives as it is superior in many ways to anything else; you can easily use the voice dictation built in for several languages, as well as translation and lookup options. You also have superior collaboration options, since you can have several people working in the same document at the same time... and it actually works well.  Please NOTE that google suite can also edit native Office docs to some extent directly.

Libre Office tries and tries but still remains a bit cludgy and rather 90's in my experience. This makes me feel disappointed since it is a good truly open piece of software.

./hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

The MS Office on wine is as buggy as MS Office on windows. Since you will not get any updates to MS Office on wine, you should install them manually.

If you do not want to exchange documents with MS Office then any of the mentioned alternatives is good.

If you want to exchange files with MS Office, then it is better to stick to MS Office. However there is no guarantee, that the MS Office is without bugs. The compatibility depends on the particular format used. Better compatibility is achieved with older well documented or open document formats as with the newest docx, xlsx or pptx formats.